# Is there an equivalant for Griddata or ScatteredInterpolant in Obj-c or Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, matlab, scipy

I have a set of data for example:

```
X Y Z 
1 3 7 
2 5 8 
1 4 9 
3 6 10
```

I would like to interpolate Z for `X=2.5` and `Y=3.5`.

I can use `interp2.griddata` from Scipy in Python or `ScatteredInterpolant` in Matlab like this:

```
z = griddata( [1 2 1 3], [3 5 4 6], [7 8 9 10], 2.5, 3.5, 'nearest' )
```

or

```
S = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,z,d);
```

Is there a way i could use something similar in Swift/Objective-c or any other compatible language to develop a small app for iOS (as well as for Android if possible) where i insert scattered data and when the user enter a value for a given X and Y he gets an interpolated value for Z (i intend to use this with 4D dimension).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is late, but I hope it will be useful in the future.
The easiest way to combine two ios languages in one project is to create a bridge header file. If your project does not have a bridge header file yet, Xcode will ask you if the bridge header file should be created. You can also create it manually: just create an Objective-C header file, for example “Bridging-Header.h”. Then go to the “Swift Compiler - Code Generation” section in the build settings and set the bridge header file name in the “Objective-C Bridging Header” field.
Good luck